# Whats best to arrange several tables on a page?

Tags: tables

i have several tables, all of those have a caption, the same number of columns, but differ in the number of rows. Those tables take about 1/3rd of the page (very similar width, mostly the same, even), so i'd like to arrange them on one or two pages (the number of tables might differ), so what's really the best way to do that?

Currently my tables are just one under the other.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be useful if you provided more information about the sizes of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you wanted.

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption} % package to use subtable environment
% for more options refer to package documentation

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!h]
  \begin{subtable}[t][][b]{0.3\textwidth}
  % [t] shows vertical alignment of subtables, use b to bottom aligned subtables in all subtables
  % [] leave it as it is
  % [b] alignment of tabular
  % {0.3\textwidth} is the space in which a table will sit
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  Column 1 & Column2\\
  \hline
  a & b\\
  \hline
  c & d\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table one}
  \end{subtable}
  \quad  % space between tables, Do not put empty line
  \begin{subtable}[t][][b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  Column 1 & Column2\\
  \hline
  a & b\\
  \hline
  c & d\\
  \hline
  e & f\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table two}
  \end{subtable}
  \quad
  \begin{subtable}[t][][b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  Column 1 & Column2\\
  \hline
  a & b\\
  \hline
  c & d\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table three}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for one page, you will have references to tables in the pages pre- and succeeding this page and this way the reader knows which page to turn to.

If however, you present the tables underneath each other: make sure the columns (or at least the total widths) match up nicely. Otherwise it will look irritating